# Why an InputStream obj cannot be nested into a BufferedReader obj directly?

Tags: java, api, io

An OutputStream obj can be connected into a PrintWriter obj directly, e.g.,

`//either is OK
new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));`

But in the case of an InputStream obj, it must be connected to a BufferedReader obj through an InputStreamReader obj, that is,

`new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); //OK
new BufferedReader(socket.getInputStream()); //doesnt work`

Is there any reason for this inconsistency of API design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java introduced Reader and Writer hierarchy (java 1.1 I think) when Input and output stream classes were already in use. Therefore using a bridge pattern they allow you to have stream classes passed into reader classes.
Further for writer also PritnerWriter is directly the bridge class which is equivalent to InputStreamReader. You will see the same thing for BufferedWriter too
For more info read up http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0114.shtml

Comment: Actually, `OutputStreamWriter` is the equivalent of `InputStreamReader`. `PrintWriter` is just an adapter that allows you to use the methods from `PrintStream` for writing to another `Writer`.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any inconsistency... you should be comparing `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`. They exist to wrap other `Reader`s and `Writer`s respectively.

The basic reason for that is that different types of `Reader`s and `Writer`s may have different ways of being initialized and different ways of functioning, not necessarily wrapping an `InputStream` or `OutputStream` at all. In your example of a `BufferedReader` wrapping an `InputStreamReader`, `InputStreamReader` can (and generally should) be initialized with both an `InputStream` and a `Charset`. Should `BufferedReader` have an overload for that, when its only job is to provide buffering?

Comment: "InputStreamReader can (and generally should) be initialized with both an InputStream and a Charset"  That's true, but the same applies to `OutputStreamWriter` and `PrintWriter`.  You should specify a charset when creating an `OutputStreamWriter`, but `PrintWriter` doesn't have an overload for that.  And PrintWriter also exists partly to wrap `Writer` objects (of any type).

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: Some classes in the IO package are handled rather poorly as far as charsets. `PrintWriter` and `FileReader` are examples. I think `PrintWriter` should probably only be allowed to wrap another `Writer` (rather than having all the other overloads) and `FileReader` just shouldn't be used... `FileInputStream` + `InputStreamReader` instead.

Comment: I agree.  And the fact that some classes rely solely on the default encoding, while others don't, is evidence that the package is partly inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

The BufferedReader is probably just decorating the InputReader being passed in.  It makes no sense for a BufferedReader to accept a class it can't decorate, like an InputStream.

Comment: So does it mean there are other choices when connecting an InputStream obj to a BufferedReader besides through an InputStreamReader ?

Comment: I believe the InputStreamReader is a 'bridge' between a Reader and an InputStream.  Read Fazal's answer below.